# handling subprocess.check_output return with quotes

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a subprocess, and it contains a way to validate a credential and returns a response like this:

```
{
"isvalid" : false
}
```

Im using this to get the response and to check if the credential passed the test:

```
def slraddresstest():
        while True:
                solarcoin_address = raw_input ("What is your SolarCoin Address: ")
                output = subprocess.check_output(['solarcoind', 'validateaddress', solarcoin_address], shell=False)
                if output != "{\"isvalid\" : false}"
                        return solarcoin_address
                else:
                        print ("Error: SolarCoin address invlaid, check and try again")
```

But on running the code I get:

```
if output != "{\"isvalid\" : false}"
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried `if output != '{"isvalid" : false}'` and `if output != """{"isvalid" : false}"""` but am getting similar syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo forgot the :

```
if output != "{\"isvalid\" : false}":
```

Comment: Arghh!!
Thanks, so sorry!

Comment: My piece of code still isnt working, when I test it and enter an invalid solarcoin_address it does not give the error.
The output looks like a dictionary so I made    if output['isvalid'] != 'false':   but that gives a   TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str.  So clearly the output is a string, but I cant seem to match it, is it because of the line breaks?

Comment: OK I figured out by trial an error I can strip the unwanted stuff from output with output = subprocess.check_output(['solarcoind', 'validateaddress', solarcoin_address], shell=False)[18:-3] to just give me 'false'

Answer (score 0):

You might have found out by now, still I am answering for reference:

solarcoind is returing json. Hence the following modifcation works (in python 3):

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['solarcoind','validateaddress',solarcoin_address], shell = False).decode("utf-8")
if( json.loads(output)['isvalid'] != False):
```

In python >= 3.6 the .decode("utf-8") might not be necessary.